# Execute ajax request via ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a php file that sends an ajax request to another file on a different domain name. That parser then receives the information, processes it, and sends it via ajax to yet another php file where the final action is executed.

So basically I'm executing an ajax request via an `AJAX` request.

However it doesn't seem to work. When I navigate to the second file directly then it's ajax fires away successfully. I only encounter a problem when I execute file 1 which attempts to execute file 2.

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible? If so, how?

Comment: Please provide the code that you are referring to.

Comment: How is another php page making an Ajax request from the original Ajax request???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX works this way:

Clientside (javascript) requests the Serverside (in this case PHP) to execute a script and return the outcome back to the Clientside.

So to answhere your question: at serverside there is no need (or even the possibility) to do AJAX. The only thing you need to do is approach the other PHP script you want to execute via the include() statement in the first file.

so file1.php would look like this:

```
<?php
//..do stuff..
include(file2.php); // Do the stuff whats in there
//..do more stuff..
//..etc..
?>
```